# Chemcompound package : how to avoid the listoffigures scan ?

Tags: table-of-contents

Another [chemcompounds](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/chemcompounds) package related question. Also maybe related to my first question relative to chemcompound and subfloat comportement [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/22478/6102)

So my question is how to avoid chemcompounds to scan from the beginning of the document  that is the listoffigures ? 
Because I guess it is the case :

an example

If I have a compound that appears in position 3 in the tex normaly but that is refered in the listoffigures because present in the caption before than it will appear as in firts position ... An example is allways better (here with Axel Sommerfeldt patch for subcaption corretc numbering)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{chemcompounds}


% Patch: Make \compound work inside (figure & table) captions
% Not neccessary for caption package version >= 3.2, but will not make any harm
\makeatletter
\let\caption@prepareslc@ORI\caption@prepareslc
\renewcommand\caption@prepareslc{%
  \let\caption@g@stepcounter\stepcounter
  \caption@prepareslc@ORI
  \let\compound@ORI\compound
  \def\compound{\let\stepcounter\caption@g@stepcounter\compound@ORI}%
}
\makeatother



\begin{document}
\listoffigures



\begin{figure}[!ht]
  \captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=empty}
  \centering
  \subfloat[\compound{wikoA}]{\rule{3cm}{2cm}}\quad
  \subfloat[\compound{wikoB}]{\rule{3cm}{2cm}}
  \caption{Wiko A and B}
  \label{wikoAandB}
\end{figure}

Here are Wiko A \compound{wikoA} and B \compound{wikoB} see fig.\ref{wikoAandB}
Of course Wiko C and D are present \compound{wikoC,wikoD}

As well as Wiko E and F \compound{wikoE,wikoF}  that you can see below. See fig. \ref{wikoEandF}

 \begin{figure}[!ht]
  \captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=empty}
  \centering
  \subfloat[\compound{wikoE}]{\rule{3cm}{2cm}}\quad
  \subfloat[\compound{wikoF}]{\rule{3cm}{2cm}}
  \caption{Wiko E (\compound{wikoE}) and F (\compound{wikoF})}
  \label{wikoEandF}



\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Related: [How to start chemical compound numbering in main text, not table of contents](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/72725/how-to-start-chemical-compound-numbering-in-main-text-not-table-of-contents)

Answer (score 1):

It's the same problem as in the other question:

```
\begingroup\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@createcompound[2][]{}
\listoffigures
\endgroup
```

This disables (temporarily) the command that steps the counter and creates the reference.

With all respect to Axel, I find that

```
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\caption@prepareslc{\renewcommand\@createcompound[2][]{}}
\makeatother
```

instead of Axel's code for disabling the problem in subcaptions is more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

The `chemcompounds` way would be to use `\compound+` inside `\caption`. This only prints an already defined compound label. `\compound*` on the other hand allows to define a compound label *without* printing it.

You will need two `latex` runs to get the numbering right.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{chemcompounds}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures

\compound*{wikoA}\compound*{wikoB}% invisible markers
\begin{figure}[!ht]
  \captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=empty}
  \centering
  \subfloat[\compound+{wikoA}]{\rule{3cm}{2cm}}\quad
  \subfloat[\compound+{wikoB}]{\rule{3cm}{2cm}}
  \caption{Wiko A and B}
  \label{wikoAandB}
\end{figure}

Here are Wiko A \compound{wikoA} and B \compound{wikoB} see fig.\ref{wikoAandB}
Of course Wiko C and D are present \compound{wikoC,wikoD}

As well as Wiko E and F \compound{wikoE,wikoF}  that you can see below. See fig. \ref{wikoEandF}

 \begin{figure}[!ht]
  \captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=empty}
  \centering
  \subfloat[\compound{wikoE}]{\rule{3cm}{2cm}}\quad
  \subfloat[\compound{wikoF}]{\rule{3cm}{2cm}}
  \caption{Wiko E (\compound+{wikoE}) and F (\compound+{wikoF})}
  \label{wikoEandF}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: See also: [How to start chemical compound numbering in main text, not table of contents](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/72725/how-to-start-chemical-compound-numbering-in-main-text-not-table-of-contents)