# Compounds defined implicitly in captions (chemscheme/chemstyle/chemcompounds)

Tags: captions, chemstyle

I'm using the `chemstyle` package to handle automatic numbering of compounds. It apparently uses the `chemcompounds` package to handle this. In the documentation for the latter, it explains compounds can be 'created' implicitly, just by referring to a label that doesn't yet exist: `\compound{label}`.

Generally this works great, but when I try to do it inside a caption, it seems to forget the compound straight away. For example, I have two figures side-by-side, I refer to different compounds in each caption, but they get assigned the same compound number. When I create a new compound in the text following, it gets the number assigned to the first compound in the figures... so basically as soon as the caption ends the package forgets all the compounds.

I should mention I'm aware it is possible to work around this (eg. by making sure things are referred to in text before captions), but I'm looking for a foolproof solution. After all I'm using LaTeX for this so I don't have to worry about misnumbered compounds constantly.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). It is always best to compose a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the chemstyle package, but the problem you describe with the use of the `\compound` command inside captions sounds like it could be solved by inserting a `\protect` command before the `\compound` command.

Comment: In moving arguments such like in `\caption` one should use the variant `\compound+` (and maybe define the label before using the “invisible” variant `\compound*`).

Answer (score 3):

Are you using the `caption` package as well? If yes, this bug was fixed in version 3.2 so updating your TeX distribution will help.

For example this MWE will work fine when compiled using `caption` package v3.2, but gives "1" every time when compiled using `caption` package v3.1m:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption,chemstyle}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\includegraphics[height=1cm]{foo}
\caption{Compound number \compound{foo}.}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\includegraphics[height=1cm]{bar}
\caption{Compound number \compound{bar}.}
\end{figure}

This should be three: \compound{foobar}
\end{document}
```

(Peter, sorry for "stealing" your MWE ;-))

Also take a look at question [Chemcompounds package and subfloat comportement ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22478/chemcompounds-package-and-subfloat-comportement) which contains a patch for the `caption` package if updating is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

Without a [full MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) it is difficult to provide much help. I tried the following and it does not seem to exhibit the problem you report:

[image]

If this example does not help, perhaps you can modify this so that it reproduces the problem you mention:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{chemstyle}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\includegraphics[height=1cm]{foo}
\caption{Compound number \compound{foo}.}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\includegraphics[height=1cm]{bar}
\caption{Compound number \compound{bar}.}
\end{figure}

This should be three: \compound{foobar}
\end{document}
```

Comment: When I compile your MWE, I get compound number 1 appearing three times.  I'm using TeXShop and pdflatex... No idea if that helps but don't know what else it could be.

Comment: Interesting, I also get `1` appearing three times, with `chemcompounds.sty 2006/12/01 v1.1.3`. What version are you using?

Comment: Oh, and if I load `chemcompounds` directly, without loading `chemstyle`, the example works. `chemstyle.sty 2011/01/05 v2.0k`.

Comment: I too am using TeXShop with pfdlatex (TeXLive 2011). I updated all the packages yesterday so not sure if that has anything to do with it. I also have `chemstyle.sty 2011/01/05 v2.0k`

Comment: I am using an older version... chemstyle.sty    2008/08/18 v1.3c.  How does one force TexShop to use updated packages?  When I put new versions in ~/Library/texmf/tex/latex/, latex still seems to load the older version (that comes packaged?)

Comment: I think it best to just update to TeXLive2011. But, if you want to only do one package at a time, I'd use the `TeX Live Utility` that comes with TeXLive (at least on a Mac), or `tlmgr` to update. If you can't find info on this site as to how to use a custom package, you should ask a new question.  But, since Jake is also seeing the same issue as you, it might not just be the `chemstyle.sty` package.

Comment: Scratch that... figure out how to create the .sty file, but now I get: 
! Package xkeyval Error: `load-configurations' undefined in families `key'.

See the xkeyval package documentation for explanation.

Comment: This seems to be a separate question as it now seems you have some package incompatibility issues.

Comment: Helpful in the extreme.  The TeX Live utility crashes on opening.

Comment: Sorry that you are having soo much difficulty. I'd recommend updating to TeXLive2011 and going from there. But perhaps wait to see others have some other suggestions.

Comment: Did that, now none of my schemes work: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32001/no-numbers-in-schemes-with-chemstyle-package